# How to disallow screenshoot in ionic 4?

Tags: android, typescript, ionic4, screenshot

How can I prevent the user from taking screenshots in ionic 4? I have tried different plugins but, in android emulator above OREO android version its not working.

I have tried these plugins-

```
 ->  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-privacyscreen
 ->  npm install cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot@1.0.3
 ->  cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-simpleprivacyscreen (for this buils will not happen, 
                                                  its showing some error related plugin)
```

please provide any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Ultimately it's [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE); does https://github.com/flotrugliocoffice/cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot-coffice not work? If not, it should be easy (enough) to adapt.

Comment: its work in real device, but not in emulator, thank you

Comment: IIRC you're right, in the emulator it still allows screenshots. (Even if it didn't you could use a native screenshot.) What's the ultimate goal? To demonstrate app functionality, or to prevent users running your app on an emulator from taking a screenshot? (DIscounting that you can just take a picture with a camera.)